# Accessing selected parameter R Markdown knit with parameters

Tags: r, parameters, markdown

I have written an R Markdown file which I "knit with parameters" in R Studio.
This knitting option presents the user (me) with a Shiny file selection dialogue box. I selected the file. It is uploaded, and I knit the file.

The file knits and produces the expected output, but I'd like to add the name of the file I selected as the parameter in the output to show the origin of the data.

Here is the YAML header:

```
title: "Status Summary"
author: "Charles Knell"
date: "11/29/2021"
output: word_document
params:
  workbook:
    label: "Latest File:"
    value: current.xlsx
    input: file
```

When I insert this into the body of the Markdown document:
`` `r basename(params$workbook) ` ``

what I get is the name of the temporary file that is created by the knitting process and not the file I selected with the input widget.

What I'd like to have is the name of the file I selected with the interactive dialogue box.
Can someone tell me how I can retrieve that so that I can insert that instead?

Comment: Indentation is important, and it looks as if your yaml header is all in column 1. It would also help if you had a MWE that produces your error. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The header in the actual document is indented properly. As for the "error", I don't think of this as an error so much as I don't know how to access the value selected via the "knit with parameters" dialogue box. The knitting process works as expected (no errors and the value that is inserted makes perfect sense in the context) There must be an object (most likely some list or other) that holds that, but I don't know the name.